# Running Parallel DockerOperator Tasks in Airflow Gives 409 Client Error

Tags: docker, airflow, dockeroperator

I am using Airflow 2.0.2 and am following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-apache-airflow-dockeroperator-with-docker-compose-57d0217c8219) on running DockerOperator tasks while running Airflow with Docker Compose. I am on MacOS, and as such I need to add this to my `docker-compose.yaml` file or I will get a Permission Denied error when using a `DockerOperator` task:

```
services:
  docker-proxy:
    image: bobrik/socat
    command: "TCP4-LISTEN:2375,fork,reuseaddr UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock"
    ports:
      - "2376:2375"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

This DAG runs completely fine, when no DockerOperator tasks are run in parallel:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator

default_args = {
'owner'                 : 'airflow',
'description'           : 'Small use of the DockerOperator',
'depend_on_past'        : False,
'start_date'            : datetime(2021, 5, 1),
'email_on_failure'      : False,
'email_on_retry'        : False,
'retries'               : 1,
'retry_delay'           : timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG('small_docker_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="5 * * * *", catchup=False) as dag:     

    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_current_date',
        bash_command='date'
        )
        
    t2 = DockerOperator(
        task_id='docker_command_hello',
        image='docker_image_task',
        container_name='task___command_hello',
        api_version='auto',
        auto_remove=True,
        command="echo hello",
        # docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
        docker_url="tcp://docker-proxy:2375", # I have to use this on MacOS or I'll get a Permission Denied error
        network_mode="bridge"
        )

    t3 = DockerOperator(
        task_id='docker_command_world',
        image='docker_image_task',
        container_name='task___command_world',
        api_version='auto',
        auto_remove=True,
        command="echo world",
        # docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
        docker_url="tcp://docker-proxy:2375", # I have to use this on MacOS or I'll get a Permission Denied error
        network_mode="bridge"
        )

    t4 = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_hello',
        bash_command='echo "Austins hello world test"'
        )

    t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4
```

However, if I make tasks `t2` and `t3` run in parallel:

```
t1 >> [t2, t3] >> t4
```

`t2` completes successfully but `t3` fails, giving this error:

```
...
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 409 Client Error: Conflict for url: http://docker-proxy:2375/v1.41/containers/create?name=task___command_world
...
docker.errors.APIError: 409 Client Error: Conflict ("Conflict. The container name "/task___command_world" is already in use by container "efe70639c7d0808fc5e609d9dc7aaa267d55d44b01eafc562cdef1b0790b89aa". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.")
```

[image]

But the container names **are different** (t2 is named `task___command_hello` and t3 is named `task___command_world`).

Because the DAG works fine when not run in parallel, I assume it has something to do with the docker_url argument (using a docker-proxy with the TCP port). This TCP proxy port is necessary to keep, because if I use `docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock"`, I will get a Permission Denied error on MacOS, and I was advised not to use `chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock` to fix the Permission Error.

So why am I getting a "Container Name Already In Use" error if the names are different, and how do I solve this?